# Haskell add writer to function

Tags: haskell, monads

here is the snippet to calculate whether knight can move to desired position within x moves:

```
import Control.Monad (guard)
import Control.Monad.Writer    

type KnightPos = (Int,Int)
-- function returning array of all possible kinght moves from desired position
moveKnight :: KnightPos -> [KnightPos]
moveKnight (c,r) = do
    (c',r') <- [ (c+2,r-1),(c+2,r+1),(c-2,r-1),(c-2,r+1)
            ,(c+1,r-2),(c+1,r+2),(c-1,r-2),(c-1,r+2)
            ]
    guard (c' `elem` [1..8] && r' `elem` [1..8])
    return (c',r')

-- nice little function tells us
-- whether knight can move to desired position within x moves
reaches :: KnightPos -> KnightPos -> Int -> Bool
reaches _ _ 0 = False
reaches from pos n =
    any (\p -> p == pos || reaches p pos (n-1)) $ moveKnight from


-- the result is True or False
-- does knight can move from cell 6,2 to cell 6,3 within 3 moves
main = print $ reachesm (6,2) (6,1) 3
```

Now i want to add Writer monad to 'reaches' funsction, but completely lost here
i come to something like,

```
-- not so nice and little yet
reachesm :: KnightPos -> KnightPos -> Int -> Writer [String] [Bool]
reachesm _ _ 0 = return [False]
reachesm from pos n = do
    tell [ "-->" ++ (show pos) ]
    p <- moveKnight from -- ???
    np <- reachesm p pos (n-1)
    return(p == pos || any np)
```

but it does not even compile. I suspect its time for monad transormers here ?

**UPD:**
So, finally we came to following rewrite, but i still unsatisfied with it, beacuse
reachesm runs differently from pure variant, it recurses all *n* steps deep, but
i expect it to stop iteration once it found the answer.
Is it hard to modify it that way ?
And another question is about laziness, it seem that in *do* block calculations are not lazy is it true ?

```
reachesm :: KnightPos -> KnightPos -> Int -> Writer [String] Bool
reachesm _    _   0 = return False
reachesm from pos n = do
   tell [ "-->" ++ (show from) ]
   let moves = moveKnight from
   np <- forM moves (\p -> reachesm p pos (n-1))
   return (any (pos ==) moves || or np)
```

Comment: Laziness depends on the monad -- since you're conceptually asking for all paths, and since the result of the writer conceptually contains all paths, then you can't get the full result of the writer while maintaining sufficient laziness. You need early exit as well -- and you can get that from adding another transformer to the stack -- look at the Exception monad, which really should be the Exit monad in your case: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/New_monads/MonadExit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it sounds like you are really committed to using the writer monad for this.  So here's a solution:

```
reachesm :: KnightPos -> KnightPos -> Int -> [Writer [String] Bool]
reachesm from pos n | from == pos = return (return True)
reachesm _ _ 0 = return (return False)
reachesm from pos n = do
    p <- moveKnight from
    map (tell [show from ++ "-->" ++ show p] >>) $ reachesm p pos (n-1)

main = print . filter fst . map runWriter $ reachesm (6,2) (6,3) 3
```

This is silly though.  The writer monad is only being used as a baroque interface to lists.  `Writer` is not the solution to your problem, despite how much you clearly want it to be.  Here is how I would write this algorithm:

```
-- returns all paths of length at most n to get to target
paths :: Int -> KnightPos -> KnightPos -> [[KnightPos]]
paths 0 _ _ = []
paths n target p 
    | p == target = return [p]
    | otherwise   = map (p:) . paths (n-1) target =<< moveKnight p

main = print $ paths 4 (6,3) (6,2)
```

No writer monad, just the friendly old `(:)` operator.

Comment: Thank you, this made things more clear, the one more thing wondering me: is ">>" operator in map, can you please explain what does it doing there ?

Comment: @Dfr, `>>` is "semicolon" for monads.  `reachesm` is building computations that look like `tell [...] >> tell [...] >> return True`, in other words `do { tell [...]; tell [...]; return True }`.  This is functional code that returns a list of _computations_, so the use of the `>>` operator comes from treating computations as first class.  Does that make sense?  Not sure how better to explain it.

Comment: So, if i got it right, omitting ">>" in map will cause compiler not to treat tell as deferred computation, but try to substitute with result of tell, although it doesn't compile without >>

Comment: @Dfr, kinda.  It's not really about deferred computation though -- laziness allows us not to worry about such things.  Without the `>>`, we would build an expression that looks like `tell [...] (tell [...] (return True))`... which is just plain nonsense.  `tell` only takes one argument and we are giving it two.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, our goal is to put this function into the Wrtier monad.

```
reaches :: KnightPos -> KnightPos -> Int -> Bool
reaches _ _ 0 = False
reaches from pos n =
    any (\p -> p == pos || reaches p pos (n-1)) $ moveKnight from
```

So, let's start with the type signature.  Just add `Writer` around the result type:

```
reaches :: KnightPos -> KnightPos -> Int -> Writer [String] Bool
```

The original function did not return a `[Bool]`, so there is no reason for the new function to return a `Writer [String] [Bool]`.  Lift the return value of the base case:

```
reaches _ _ 0 = return False
```

As you suspected, it gets a little trickier to do the recursive case. Let's start out like you did by `tell`ing the current `pos`, which you did right.

```
reaches from pos n = do
    tell ["-->" ++ show pos]
```

`moveKnight` is not in the writer monad so we don't have to bind it using `<-` to call it.  Just use `let` (i.e. we could substitute `moveKnight pos` whenever we use our new variable if we wanted):

```
    let moves = moveKnight from
```

Now let's get the list of recursive results.  This time we *do* have to bind, since we are getting the `Bool` out of a `Writer [String] Bool`.  We will use the monadic variant of `map`, `mapM :: (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]`:

```
    np <- mapM (\p -> reachesm p pos (n-1)) ps
```

Now `np :: [Bool]`.  So then we just finish off your logic:

```
    return (any (pos ==) moves || or np)
```

`or :: [Bool] -> Bool` is just `any id`.

So remember, to bind a variable, when you want to get the `a` from an `m a`, use `<-`, otherwise use `let`.

To use it from `main` you can use `runWriter :: Writer w a -> (w,a)`:

```
main = print $ runWriter (reachesm (6,2) (6,1) 3)
```

This code still has an error, but it compiles and yields what you told it to over the writer channel, so it should be enough that you can debug the remaining issue easily.  Hope this helped.

Comment: Wow, thank you for extended explanation, but the goal of task was to add writer to record path, which knight passes from start to finish, but it records something that is not desired. I updated my first post to reflect your rewrite.

Comment: @Dfr, Oh... it looks like monad you want is `WriterT [String] []`... or `ListT (Writer [String])`. Not sure which -- they might be identical.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version that works:

```
main = print $ runWriterT (reachesm (6,2) (6,5) 4)

reachesm :: KnightPos -> KnightPos -> Int -> WriterT [String] [] Bool
reachesm _ _ (-1) = return False
reachesm from pos n 
  | from == pos = tell [ "-->" ++ (show from) ] >> return True
  | otherwise   = 
   do
     p <- lift (moveKnight from) 
     t <- reachesm p pos (n-1)
     guard t 
     tell [ "-->" ++ (show from) ]
     return True
```

Also your `moveKnight` function can be written like this:

```
moveKnight :: KnightPos -> [KnightPos]
moveKnight (c,r) = filter legal possible
       where possible = [ (c+2,r-1),(c+2,r+1),(c-2,r-1),(c-2,r+1)
                        ,(c+1,r-2),(c+1,r+2),(c-1,r-2),(c-1,r+2)]  
             legal (c',r') = (c' `elem` [1..8] && r' `elem` [1..8])
```

Comment: Your first version doesn't seem to do what Dfr presumably wants (gather the path/paths in the writer). Your second version also doesn't exactly work: `lookup True $ runWriterT (reachesm (6,2) (1,1) 3)` gives `Nothing`, for example.

Comment: Thanks! First version seem kinda what i was looking for, but i wonder why it keeps recursing after (elem pos ps) returned true ? Seems like haskell decided to give up its laziness for some reason and evaluates 'reachesm' few levels deep even if we can reach withtin 1 move.

Comment: I guess this is because of bind operator, but the second version also recurses eagerly, this time because never hits the first guard condition and its also weird.

Comment: @Travis Brown, I wasn't sure exactly what was wanted, but I see now that the first version wasn't it =D. I fixed the second version so that it does what is needed.

Comment: didn't worked for me "execWriterT $ reachesm (6,2) (6,1) 3" Should not return []

Comment: @Dfr, well it is one off, it counts the start as one move, try `runWriterT (reachesm (6,2) (6,5) 4)`

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit easier (for me at least) to think of this as looking for a path in a tree.

First we import a couple of functions from [`Data.Tree`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0-latest/html/libraries/containers-0.4.0.0/Data-Tree.html):

```
import Data.Tree (levels, unfoldTree)
```

Now we write a function for unfolding the tree with history, take the top `n + 1` levels of the tree, and see if they contain the desired position:

```
reaches :: KnightPos -> KnightPos -> Int -> Maybe [KnightPos]
reaches from pos n = lookup pos . concat . take (n + 1) $ levels tree
  where
    tree = unfoldTree unfolder (from, [])
    unfolder (p, hist) = ((p, hist'), map (flip (,) hist') $ moveKnight p)
      where hist' = p : hist
```

This gives us a path from the end position to the beginning in the given number of steps, if it exists:

```
*Main> reaches (6,2) (6,1) 3
Just [(6,1),(7,3),(8,1),(6,2)]
```

(We could of course reverse this if we wanted a path from start to finish.)

This is a quick solution off the top of my head, and it's not necessarily very efficient, but I find it conceptually straightforward.

Comment: This is pretty elegant solution, and gives desired answer also, but main purpose of my task was understanding of monads.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my late attempt:

```
import Control.Monad

type KnightPos = (Int,Int)  

moveKnight :: KnightPos -> [KnightPos]  
moveKnight (c,r) = do  
  (c',r') <- [(c+2,r-1),(c+2,r+1),(c-2,r-1),(c-2,r+1)  
             ,(c+1,r-2),(c+1,r+2),(c-1,r-2),(c-1,r+2)]  
  guard (c' `elem` [1..8] && r' `elem` [1..8])  
  return (c',r') 


findpath :: KnightPos -> KnightPos -> Int -> [[KnightPos]]
findpath start end steps = trail [start] steps
   where trail curtrail steps = do
               nextstep <- moveKnight $ last curtrail
               if steps == 1 then
                  do guard (nextstep == end)
                     return (curtrail ++ [nextstep])
                else trail (curtrail ++ [nextstep]) (steps - 1)
```